# Does reassigning partitions of __consumer_offsets topic cause problems?

Tags: apache-kafka

We are runnning 25 brokers. But partitions of the __consumer_offsets topic spreads on only 3 brokers and it's not fully available as we intended. This may not a problem because kafka supports reassigning partition across brokers. But we hesitate to reassign them because topic is __consumer_offsets.

Cluster information :

- Broker version: 0.11.0.2
- number of brokers : 25

__consumer_offsets topic status :

- number of partitions : 50
- number of replica : 3
- Broker spread : 3 (50 partitions are placed on 3 partitions)

My questions is : Does reassigning partitions of __consumer_offsets topic leads problem or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reassign partitions of __consumer_offset , there wouldn't be any issue as it's reassignment is treated the same way as other topics

Answer (score 2):

Currently, we are using Kafka 2.11-1.1.1. I had a problem with reassigning some partitions of consumer_offset. it caused a rolling restart of all Kafka instances due to this exception in fetcher thread.

```
kafka.common.OffsetsOutOfOrderException: Out of order offsets found in append to __consumer_offsets-31.
```

I don't know why but I think we should do it in silence time.